# Categorical histograms in seaborn from a dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

Consider I have the following dataframe:

| sample | tca_after | avg_length_after | cd_after | tca_before | avg_length_before | cd_before |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.015385 | 50.513499 | 1.4 | 0.005139 | 31.844415 | 0.4 |
| 2 | 0.005040 | 19.209373 | 1.0 | 0.004603 | 20.831459 | 0.6 |
| 3 | 0.057218 | 31.869649 | 10.0 | 0.008687 | 17.926937 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 0.037175 | 45.543659 | 3.8 | 0.035760 | 56.937708 | 2.8 |

I want to compare TCA, avg_length, and CD, before and after a certain process. So I would like to create three categorical histograms like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0BtO.png) using seaborn. On x-axis I have all four samples, on y-axis I have either TCA, avg_length or CD for both before and after. I have no idea how to do it :(

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the before and after columns could together, and add a new column, e.g. "when" to indicate before vs after. That new column can then be used as "hue".

Here is how you could create a histogram:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348014')[0]

df_before = df[['sample', 'tca_before', 'avg_length_before', 'cd_before']]
df_before = df_before.rename(columns={'tca_before': 'tca', 'avg_length_before': 'avg_length', 'cd_before': 'cd'})
df_before['when'] = 'before'
df_after = df[['sample', 'tca_after', 'avg_length_after', 'cd_after']]
df_after = df_after.rename(columns={'tca_after': 'tca', 'avg_length_after': 'avg_length', 'cd_after': 'cd'})
df_after['when'] = 'after'
df_new = pd.concat([df_before, df_after]).reset_index()

sns.histplot(data=df_new, x='tca', hue='when', palette='copper_r', multiple='dodge')
```

[image: converting a before and after column to hue in sns.histplot]

To create a bar plot with the sample IDs on the x axis, you can change `sns.histplot` to `sns.barplot`:

```py
sns.barplot(data=df_new, x='sample', y='tca', hue='when', palette='copper_r', dodge=True)
```

[image: sns.barplot from before and after columns]